# Is it possible to split huge javascript file by few smaller files preserving its structure?

Tags: javascript

I have pretty big javascript class with bunch of methods stored in a single js file. This methods can be logically categorized like common methods, methods to filter data, navigation methods etc. Now I want this class being split by separate files each containing its own specific category methods and leaving all properties and common methods in the current file. Shortly speaking I need something that c# `partial` keyword is used for.

I would like to avoid using `prototype` as it means I have to type class name for every function like `class.prototype.functionname = function () { ... }` that does not look great.

**UPDATE**: This is how my class looks like

```
function MyClass() {
    var self = this;
    self.common = function() {...}
    self.filterData = function() {...}
    self.navigate = function() {...}
}
```

I do not know how to handle `self` properly with prototypes or extension

Comment: Why are you against `prototype`? This is precisely what it was made for. You could probably merge two objects together using some extra code, but that sort of takes away from the readability of JS.

Comment: I'll use prototype if only there are no better way to go. IMO it's Ok for adding few methods, but if you have dozens of them it looks a bit ugly, as class name repeated too many times thought single file

Comment: Show us your current structure (doesn't need to be all the code) which you don't want to break up

Comment: `SomeObj.prototype = { fn1: ..., fn2: ..., ... }` or `$.extend(SomeObj.prototype, { fn1: ..., ... });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your class does not use the prototype, you have little chance - it is one [too] big function. However, such big functions shouldn't exist anyway, are you sure you need it to be a class (with multiple instances)? Then you should move the functions to the prototype as far as you can. If not, a singleton would make more sense for you, which is essentially nothing more than an object literal. You also might have a look at the [[revealing] module pattern](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#modulepatternjavascript), which is what you need (or one of its flavors) - the (sub) modules usually can be spread easily across different files, potentially using a dependency tracking loader.

If it does, you can easily split it up into the single parts. That does not mean you would need to repeat `class.prototype.… = …`, you can just use helper functions like `extend`

```
MyFavLibrary.extend(class.prototype, {
    functionname: function functionname() {…},
    …
});
```

or a simple IEFE-closure:

```
(function(proto) {
    // even some place for static, private helper functions
    proto.functionname = functionname() {…};
    …
})(class.prototype);
```

Comment: Ok, I was unaware of `.extend`. It totally meets my goal as I do not have to retype my class name. Thank you

Comment: I've updated question as you asked. Could you please show me how the extension will look like in my case. I do not know how to handle `self` properly. Thanks

Comment: There are many possibilities, I extended my answer for the first case. You should read the linked chapter on module pattern(s).

Comment: To @Bergi: Sorry, but I do not completely understand your idea. I see your recommendation over refactoring it to singleton, but if I want to leave it as is i.e. `function MyClass() {...}`, can I still make it extendable with `.extend` or `prototype`? Could you please write example for my specific case? I tried, but nothing works: new files do not see `self` variable defined inside main module.

Comment: Yes, you will need to use a prototype which you can extend from the different files. And yes, prototype function do not have access to any private-scoped variables in the constructor, like `self`. Use `this` instead - those functions usually are invoked in the context of your instance