# Multiple files using a single javascript prototype that uses object literal

Tags: javascript

Basically, I found the javascript library where the API uses some object literal. I am trying to figure out how to separate them on different javascript files for easier reading. There is the file that has like 30 different functions nested in a single object... I am trying to separate them. The example below is simplified to show my point.

```
BasicGame.Game.prototype = {

var1: function () { blah blah},
var2: function () { blah blah},
var3: function () { blah blah},
var4: function () { blah blah}
}
```

How an you take out var3 and var4 and put in them in another object literal that shares same Basic.Game object? If I wrote BasicGame.Game again, it would overwrite the original object literal.

Comment: Assign properties instead of overwriting the object.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Defining a Javascript prototype](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17474390/defining-a-javascript-prototype) and [Is it possible to split huge javascript file by few smaller files preserving its structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12483333/is-it-possible-to-split-huge-javascript-file-by-few-smaller-files-preserving-its)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can augment Object with the following code:

```
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, "partial", {
    enumerable: false,
    configurable: false,
    set: function (value) {
        if (value.constructor === Object) {
            for (prop in value) {
                if (value.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                    this[prop] = value[prop];
                }
            }
        }
        return this;
    },
    get: function () { return this;}
});
```

Then you can use this augment to add literals to any object like so:

```
//first file
BasicGame.Game.prototype = {

    var1: function () { alert("blah blah"); },
    var2: function () { alert("blah blah"); },
}

//second file
BasicGame.Game.prototype.partial = {

    var3: function () { alert("blah blah"); },
    var4: function () { alert("blah blah"); }
}

var game = new BasicGame.Game();
```

now ***game*** will show all four properties as they "shine through" its constructor's prototype.

Comment: Whoa, I am impressed by this.

Answer (score 2):

You can write `BasicGame.Game.prototype.var3 = function() { }` in another file and it won't overwrite the functions already in there.

For example, `file1.js`:

```
BasicGame.Game.prototype = {
    var1: function () { blah blah},
    var2: function () { blah blah}
}
```

And `file2.js`:

```
BasicGame.Game.prototype.var3 = function () { blah blah};
BasicGame.Game.prototype.var4 = function () { blah blah};
```

Just make sure that `file1.js` is included first or use the dot notation for both files.

Comment: That would work. But is it possible to make another object literal? Seems a bit inelegant to write BasicGame.Game.prototype.somevar over and over again.

Comment: @user1142285 You could store BasicGame.Game.prototype in a temporary variable and do `proto.var3 = function() { bla blah }`. The only alternative is using a library like jQuery to merge object literals.